# Complete Cover Background Image issue

Tags: css, background-image

I currently have a complete cover background image.

Here is the code:

```
#back{ /* #back is a div */
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:-1;

    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/bg.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/bg.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

It appears to work well, but I discovered a glitch in it that I was hoping someone could help me with.

If I reduce the browser window size from the bottom up to say half of my page and then use the browser's scroll bars to scroll down, the background doesn't follow.

I'm left with something that looks like the below images

[image: image after scrolling]

Is there a way I can combat this? I wish the background image to cover in all circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a problem of `background-size:cover`. It's a problem of `position:absolute`

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/8b27V/

Comment: Actually nevermind. position:fixed; does the trick. Thanks for pointing my error out to me! I was obviously looking in the wrong place

Comment: As I mentioned, it needs position:fixed to work. Your solution seems to work, but as soon as you add the need to scroll (i.e. a fixed height content box) then it still happens. http://jsfiddle.net/8b27V/1/ try it.

Comment: Would just like to add that I had a style of width:100% on the div which was causing issues too. I removed it, and it worked fine.